# Android call functionality

Tags: android

I have implemented the call functionality in the Android and it's working fine. When I run this app in India, it's working fine, but there is an issue in USA. My client who is in USA is testing the app he found this issue.

It's a simple functionality. Given a phone number `320492727200` (+32 Belgium country code), when I click on this number, it will dial the same number (tested in India). Now the issue is, when my client clicks on the same number, it will dial `011320492727200`. I have done too much research, but I can't find the solution.

My code

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
     Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
     callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:320492727200"));
     startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Please, post code how do you start call

Comment: Please share your code as well. A wild guess is soeme trouble with `String.format()`, that does surprising things in regards to locales.

Comment: public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:320492727200"));
    startActivity(callIntent);

   }

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is since he is the US, the country code "011" is included when dialing. Try making a dial to +320492727200

Comment: 1) 0320492727200
2) 320492727200
3) 0492727200
4) 492727200
5) +320492727200
i tried all the above option